# why my blender serial communication is lagging

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I have a 9dof IMU that sends a continuous stream of quaternions over serial communication the values seems fine and very responsive over something like putty or a normal python script

the problem happens when trying to use it with modal operator on blender it looks like the data is always lagging behind a lot (like if I tilt the imu 90 degrees it only shows up on blender 5 seconds after)
it's worth mentioning that the animation is smooth the problem is the late update of the serial data with blender verified using print statements with no animation at all

Idk I hope I missed something obvious since it's my first script for blender feel free to ask for any further details that I might be missing

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Quaternion
from bpy.props import BoolProperty
import serial





object_name = "LP_Hands"  # Replace with the name of your object
obj = bpy.data.objects[object_name]
right_hand = obj.pose.bones.get("hand.R")

# Set the rotation mode once
obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
right_hand.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'


#FPS = 30        # use 30 if system performance is poor
#FPS = 60
FPS = 90
#FPS = 360

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()





def read_quat():
    dataPacket = ser.readline()
    dataPacket = str(dataPacket, 'utf-8')
    numbers = dataPacket.split("\t")

    if(len(numbers) != 4):
        return
    
    w = (numbers[0])
    x = (numbers[1])
    y = (numbers[2])
    z = (numbers[3])
    
    w = w.strip('\x00')
    x = x.strip('\x00')
    y = y.strip('\x00')
    z = z.strip('\x00\n')

    try:
        w = float(w)
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        z = float(z)
    except ValueError:
        return
    
    quat = [w, x, y, z]
    return quat







class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs itself from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            ser.close()
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
              self.update_orientation(context)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def update_orientation(self, context):
        if obj is None:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, f"Object '{object_name}' not found.")
            self.running = False
            return

        quaternion_values = read_quat()
        if quaternion_values is None:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Invalid quaternion values.")
            return

        print(quaternion_values)
        quaternion = Quaternion(quaternion_values)
        right_hand.rotation_quaternion = quaternion
        
    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1/FPS, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)





def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalTimerOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalTimerOperator.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Modal Timer Operator" for quick access).
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

snippet of the console prints:

```
[0.643, -0.761, 0.072, 0.018]
[0.646, -0.759, 0.071, 0.017]
[0.65, -0.756, 0.07, 0.016]
[0.652, -0.754, 0.07, 0.017]
[0.653, -0.753, 0.07, 0.017]
```